# join with different table with different condition

Tags: mysql, sql

My Tables

Renovationinfo

```
BlockCode|arsehRow|SakhtemanRow
-------------------------------
1        |1       |00          
2        |2       |00          
3        |3       |01
```

ArsehMalk

```
BlockCode|arsehRow|name
------------------------
1        |1       |a          
2        |2       |b
```

ApartmanMalk

```
BlockCode|arsehRow|SakhtemanRow|name
-------------------------------------------------
3        |3       |01          |d
```

i want join `Renovationinfo` with `ArsehMalk` if `SakhtemanRow=='00'`

and join  `Renovationinfo` with `ApartmanMalk` if `SakhtemanRow<>'00'`

I write this query But this does not return any things.

```
Select name
From 
    Renovationinfo r 
Left Join
     ArsehMalk m1 On m1.BlockCode = r.BlockCode And
     m1.arsehRow = r.arsehRow And r.SakhtemanRow = '00' 
Left Join
     ApartmanMalk m2 On m2.BlockCode = r.BlockCode And
     m2.arsehRow = r.arsehRow And
     m2.SakhtemanRow=r.SakhtemanRow  And 
     r.SakhtemanRow<>'00'
```

I want get this output

```
BlockCode|arsehRow|name
-------------------------------
1        |1       |a          
2        |2       |b          
3        |3       |d
```

Comment: Can you please share the output you'd like to get for this sample? It will make the question much easier to understand.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that query. Are you sure it's not the data that's bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has one fundamental issue:  `name` is ambiguous.  You can fix this as:

```
select coalesce(m1.name, m2.name) as name
```

Because you want additional columns:

```
select r.BlockCode, r.arehRow, coalesce(m1.name, m2.name) as name
```